# Symbol BoundingBox for gcloud document_text_detection

Tags: python, google-cloud-vision

I'm using gcloud's [async document text detection](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/pdf) feature within Vision.

I would like symbol bounding boxes but the API doesn't output them for files over 1 page.

Below is the python implementation using google-cloud-vision==2.6.2.

```
from google.cloud import vision
def ocr_async(file_id):
    input_location = f'{file_location}/{file_id}.pdf'
    output_location = f'{ocr_output_loc}/{file_id}/'
    gcs_prefix= f'gs://{storage_bucket}/'

    mime_type = 'application/pdf'
    batch_size = 50

    client = vision.ImageAnnotatorClient()
    feature = vision.Feature(type_=vision.Feature.Type.DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION)
    gcs_source = vision.GcsSource(uri=gcs_prefix+input_location)
    input_config = vision.InputConfig(gcs_source=gcs_source, mime_type=mime_type)
    gcs_destination = vision.GcsDestination(uri=gcs_prefix+output_location)
    output_config = vision.OutputConfig(gcs_destination=gcs_destination, batch_size=batch_size)

    async_request = vision.AsyncAnnotateFileRequest(
        features=[feature], input_config=input_config,
        output_config=output_config)

    operation = client.async_batch_annotate_files(requests=[async_request])
```

Here is a snippet of the json for a 1 page file. The word has a bounding box and the symbol, "S", has a bounding box.

```
"words":[{"boundingBox":{"normalizedVertices":[{"x":0.12745099,"y":0.15277778},{"x":0.2009804,"y":0.15277778},{"x":0.2009804,"y":0.16540404},{"x":0.12745099,"y":0.16540404}]},"symbols":[{"boundingBox":{"normalizedVertices":[{"x":0.12745099,"y":0.15277778},{"x":0.13398694,"y":0.15277778},{"x":0.13398694,"y":0.16540404},{"x":0.12745099,"y":0.16540404}]},"text":"S","confidence":1}
```

Here is a snippet of the ocr result for a document > 1 page. This result has the word bounding box but not the symbol. It also has different properties (detectedLanguages). It seems like it's using a different API even though I'm calling the same function.

```
"words":[{"property":{"detectedLanguages":[{"languageCode":"en","confidence":1}]},"boundingBox":{"normalizedVertices":[{"x":0.26984128,"y":0.05952381},{"x":0.31746033,"y":0.05952381},{"x":0.31746033,"y":0.083333336},{"x":0.26984128,"y":0.083333336}]},"symbols":[{"text":"T","confidence":0.9649447},{"text":"h","confidence":0.9748979}
```

Is there a way to require symbol bounding boxes when calling the function? Along those lines, is there a way to remove some output properties like confidence? (trim down the output)

**Edit:**
It looks like it has to do something with the PDF type and not so much the length. [Here](https://github.com/redbloons33/testFiles) are two different 1-page PDFs along with their outputs. Acutepsych doesn't have symbol bounding boxes but the SaveAsPDF file does. SaveAsPDF was created in Word and Acutepsych was found online.

I'll also mention that [dense document text detection](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/fulltext-annotations) gets symbol vertices for image files but I can't get it to work with PDFs.

Comment: May I request both the 1 page sample file and the more than 1 page file that you are using to produce this output ?

Comment: You can look [here](https://github.com/redbloons33/testFiles) for the in/out. I added an edit above as well.

Comment: It appears that this is a case of inaccuracy or incompatibility issues with the pdf Files, I have replicated your code and reproduced the other file(SaveAsPDF) . I also tried another file with similar text and produced output with symbols bounding box. It possibly depends what application was used to save the pdf file or version.  I would suggest to file an Issue for this by following steps here: https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#issue_reports
 Describe your concern and fill in appropriate information with your inquiry.